# Refresh AWS Quicksight automatically

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-quicksight

I do not want a scheduled refresh which according the documentation is daily, weekly, monthly. I want to refresh whenever I want, but without going on Quicksight and manually pressing refresh.

Wondering if it's possible to automatically refresh through a script whenever new data is loaded into a database and sent to Quicksight. Scenario: Quicksight is refreshed with new data possibly every couple of minutes or hours throughout the day.

Comment: It is possible to trigger a refresh with the CreateIngestion API. Details are explained in this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/event-driven-refresh-of-spice-datasets-in-amazon-quicksight/

Answer (score 4):

**Currently quicksight doesn’t facilitate custom data refresh periods. But you can find hourly refresh option in enterprise edition.**

For Standard or Enterprise editions, you can choose Daily, Weekly, or Monthly. **Daily**: Repeats every day Weekly: Repeats on the same day of each week **Monthly**: Repeats on the same day of each month. To refresh data on the 29th, 30th or 31st day of the month, choose Last day of month from the list.

- For **Enterprise edition alone**, you can choose Hourly. This setting
  refreshes your data set every hour, beginning at the time you choose.
  So, if you select 1:05 as the starting time, the next refresh happens
  at 2:05
- If you decide to use an hourly refresh, you can't also use additional
  refresh schedules. To create an hourly schedule, you must remove any
  other existing schedules for that data set; and you must remove any
  existing hourly schedule before you can create a daily, weekly, or
  monthly schedule.
- Starting: Choose a date for the refresh to start.
- At: Specify the time when the refresh should start. Use HH:MM and
  24-hour format, for example 13:30.
- Choose create

Comment: Have anyone suggested this API control of refreshes? Is it something we can vote for somewhere? (asking cause I could not find it anywhere)

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2018, QuickSight does not have any APIs for accomplishing  this.